# My ReactJS flux App has too many 'actiontype' constants, how can I separate and namespace them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I'm building a flux app that involves many different types of data, and the CRUD style modification of the resources. This leads to the a large number of ActionTypes. Most of them follow the same pattern, `REQUEST_ENTITY, REQUEST_ENTITY_SUCCESS, REQUEST_ENTITY_ERROR`, and so on.

How do I separate them into namespaced constants?

Ideally instead of accessing them like:

```
ActionTypes.REQUEST_ENTITY
```

I could access them in a more sane way like,

```
ActionTypes.entity.REQUEST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply merge multiple objects (perhaps exported from different files) into `ActionTypes`.

```javascript
// entity_actions.js
module.exports = {
  entity: {
    REQUEST: "entity.REQUEST",
    DELETE: "entity.DELETE",
  }
};

// user_actions.js
module.exports = {
  user: {
    REQUEST: "user.REQUEST",
    DELETE: "user.DELETE",
  }
};

// actions.js
var entityActions = require("./entity_actions");
var userActions = require("./user_actions");
var ActionTypes = Object.assign({}, entityActions, userActions);
```

You can use something like [`Underscore#extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) or [object-assign](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-assign) if `Object.assign` isn't available in your environment.

---

I personally use a small module I called `nestedKeyMirror` that takes a big nested object and automatically generates values based on the nesting:

```javascript
function nestedKeyMirror(obj, namespace) {
  namespace = namespace || [];
  for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === null) {
      obj[key] = namespace.concat([key]).join(":");
    } else if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      obj[key] = nestedKeyMirror(obj[key], namespace.concat([key]));
    }
  }

  return obj;
}
```

For example, in one app, I have the following action types defined:

```javascript
var actionTypes = nestedKeyMirror({
  LAYOUT: {
    RESIZE_PANE: null
  },

  CANVAS: {
    SET_PROPERTY: null
  },

  SHAPES: {
    ADD: null,
    SET_PROPERTY: null,
    SEND_BACKWARD: null,
    SEND_FORWARD: null,
    SEND_TO_BACK: null,
    SEND_TO_FRONT: null
  },

  SELECTION: {
    SELECT: null,
    DESELECT_ALL: null
  },

  HISTORY: {
    ADD: null,
    SELECT_INDEX: null
  }
});
```

This would give, e.g., `actionTypes.SHAPES.ADD` with an automatically-generated string value of `"SHAPES:ADD"`. This technique can be combined with the object-merging strategy, above, to easily create deeply nested action type constants.

[Update: it looks like someone recently released a package that does the nested key mirroring on npm: [keymirror-nested](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keymirror-nested)]

---

If the problem is that all your action types look similar, you could easily create a function to generate them (ES6 computed property syntax used here):

```javascript
function generateActionType(type, base) {
  return {
    [base]: `${base}_${type}`,
    [`${base}_SUCCESS`]: `${base}_${type}_SUCCESS`,
    [`${base}_ERROR`]: `${base}_${type}_ERROR`
  };
}

ActionTypes.entity = {};
Object.assign(ActionTypes.entity, generateActionType("ENTITY", "REQUEST"));
Object.assign(ActionTypes.entity, generateActionType("ENTITY", "DELETE"));

ActionTypes.entity.REQUEST_SUCCESS === "REQUEST_ENTITY_SUCCESS";
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not skip the constants, and just use the string values? Sure, you may mistype one from time to time, but you could just as easily mistype the constant names, right? Your unit tests will fail in the same place, either way, and you'll know what's wrong.

Without compile-time checking, the main value of these kinds of constant lists is that the code is a bit more self-documenting, but if you're that consistent in your naming conventions, it might not be worth the extra effort to write them all out as constants?

(That was kind of a non-answer, I guess, but I've had this same conversation with others, so probably worth adding to the discussion here, too.)

Comment: In theory if you use constants everywhere, comparing action types should be faster (like in giant `switch` statement in stores). But is it really worth it?

Comment: I know my question is quite discussable, apologies. I've been looking at reflux, and wondering if could take some ideas from that.